# Streaming encoded video in Adobe AIR Application

Tags: air, video-streaming, video-encoding, h.264

I am developing a desktop application in Adobe AIR that will be used to stream the user's camera video to a wowza media server. I want to encode the video on the fly, means transmit the H.264 encoded video instead of the default flash player encoded video for quality purpose. Is there any way around for this?

Waiting for the help from people around,

Rick

Answer (score 1):

H.264 encoding is usually done in Native Code C or C++ because it is a cpu 
intensive set of algorithms. The source code for [x264](http://www.videolan.org/x264.html) can give you an 
idea of the code required but it is a tough read if you start from scratch.

Here is a [book](http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/cgi-bin/bookhome/106582274?CRETRY=1&SRETRY=0) to get you started or you can read the original [AVC standard](http://www.iso.ch/iso/en/CatalogueDetailPage.CatalogueDetail?CSNUMBER=43058&ICS1=35&ICS2=40&ICS3=) 
if you suffer from insomnia.